# Difference between ASP.NET Web App and ASP.NET MVC 3 Empty Web App?

Tags: asp.net

I want to build my own web framework, and I want to build it in C#. I figure the easiest way to get started is to use ASP.NET to handle all the server communication stuff. The rest I want to build my self. I know next to nothing about ASP.NET. (But know C#, the MVC pattern, and other web frameworks quite well).

In Visual Studio 2010 I see

- ASP.NET Web Application
- ASP.NET MVC 2 Empty Web Application
- ASP.NET MVC 3 Empty Web Application

I figure one of these should be good as a base. I just want some "entry point" into some C# code. I started with PHP so it's a little bit weird for me to not be able to just load up a file in my browser. Anyway, which should I use? What's the difference between a plain ASP.NET Web App and an empty MVC 3 app? If it's "empty" it shouldn't be using any of the MVC framework, should it? I just want to make sure I use the latest and greatest "ASP" for handling the server stuff before I embark down this road.

Comment: I see now there's also an "ASP.NET Empty Web Application" which is even emptier. Doesn't even have a start page...that might be good (if I knew where to go from there).

Comment: Almost a year now....still working on this :D Very slowly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you shouldn't start with an Empty Web Application, because it just gives you the references to the assemblies, but doesn't give you any sample code.

**ASP.NET Web App**, is a NOT empty web app (meaning it has a basic setup of files), meant to be used with ASP.NET WebForms. For tutorials: http://www.asp.net/web-forms

**ASP.NET MVC 2 Empty Web Application** is an empty project, meant to be used with ASP.NET MVC version 2 (the current version). For tutorials:  http://www.asp.net/mvc

**ASP.NET MVC 3 Empty Web Application** is an empty project, meant to be used with ASP.NET MVC version 3 (now a release candidate). For info: http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3

Before creating your framework, dig into the tutorials, play around, and only then start building your framework.

And about WebForms vs MVC, that's a whole other discussion. I personally switched for my new project to MVC, and perhaps it's better suitable for your Framework app.

Comment: Well, I intend on replacing 99% of the stuff those frameworks provide... don't they have some common base (ASP.NET) on which they are built? I want that... so I can start at the same place and then build up from there. I'll do some reading though.. thanks. Didn't realize Web App == WebForms.

Comment: Web App != WebForms , see the MVC project types also have Web Application in their name. 
All of them are based on ASP.NET, which is generally a pipeline, in which you can plug in HttpModules and HttpHandlers for you to create your own Framework. Still start with the tutorials, and learn how everything works, before commencing such a huge task of building your own framework.